# How to change the siblings of xml into parent and child nodes according to their attributes using xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt, parent-child, siblings

the input is

```html
<p style="abc">hbfg</p>
<r style="cds">bhf</r>
<r style="cds"> bhfsh</r>
<p style="abc">pofj</p>
<r style="abc"> bchs</r>
```

the expected output should be

```html
<p style="abc">hbfg
    <r style="cds">bhf</r>
    <r style="cds"> bhfsh</r></p>
<p style="abc">pofj
    <r style="abc"> bchs</r></p>
```

How to convert it using xslt.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: your can question can be easier to read/understand if you [format your code](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html) and use stackoverflow's [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: Hi @Douglas.P i changed the question hope you under stand my problem and answer to my problem. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two versions of an XSLT stylesheet which will process the XML
file you posted, one for [xslt-2.0](/questions/tagged/xslt-2.0) which introduced a convenient
`xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with=pattern` element for this
use case, and, for maximum portability, one for [xslt-1.0](/questions/tagged/xslt-1.0) using
XPath to do the grouping. Both versions use `doc/text` as the logical
root of the tree and `xsl:apply-templates` to make the most of
the built-in template rules. Mind the whitespace handling.

More examples of  *flat file transformation* at
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxslt%5Dflat+file+transformation)
and the XSLT 1.0 FAQ, now at
[archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20180305021934/dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/flatfile.html).

---

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="doc/text">
    <chapter>
      <title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@style='TRH2']"/>
      </title>
      <research>
        <title>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@style='TRRef']"/>
        </title>
        <reftext>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@style='TRRefText']"/>
        </reftext>
      </research>
      <sections>
        <xsl:for-each-group 
          select="p[not(@style) or @style='TRH7']"
          group-starting-with="p[@style='TRH7']"
        >
          <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::p[1]"/>
          </title>
          <paragraphs>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[self::p][position()>1]">
              <para-text>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
              </para-text>
            </xsl:for-each> 
          </paragraphs>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </sections>
    </chapter>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="p[@style='TRRefText']">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foot-note">
    <footnoteref>
      <id><xsl:value-of select="@id-rel"/></id>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </footnoteref>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

---

The XSLT 1.0 version (in the third `xsl:template`) uses an XPath
expression to group the non-title `p` elements between current and
next subsection title element (`p[@style='TRH7']`), and a `mode="para"`
clause to avoid processing the title as both title and paragraph.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="doc/text">
    <chapter>
      <title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@style='TRH2']" />
      </title>
      <research>
        <title>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@style='TRRef']" />
        </title>
        <reftext>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@style='TRRefText'] "/>
        </reftext>
      </research>
      <sections>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@style='TRH7']" />
      </sections>
    </chapter>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="p[@style='TRRefText']">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[@style='TRH7']">
    <title><xsl:apply-templates/></title>
    <paragraphs>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="para"
        select="following-sibling::p[not(@style='TRH7')]
               [generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[@style='TRH7'][1])
              = generate-id(current())]"
      />
    </paragraphs>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p" mode="para">
    <para-text><xsl:apply-templates/></para-text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foot-note">
    <footnoteref>
      <id><xsl:value-of select="@id-rel"/></id>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </footnoteref>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**UPDATE**: Additional explanation as requested in comment.

Your own code is very close to what I posted so I'll expand on how to group elements using XSLT 1.0. Each sub-section in the document is triggered by the style of its title (`p[@style='TRH7']`), activating the 3rd template:

```xml
<xsl:template match="p[@style='TRH7']">
  <title><xsl:apply-templates/></title>
  <paragraphs>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="para"
      select="following-sibling::p[not(@style='TRH7')]
             [generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[@style='TRH7'][1])
            = generate-id(current())]"
    />
  </paragraphs>
</xsl:template>
```

This template emits a sub-section title (using a built-in template rule), then collects the following non-title paragraphs
(`following-sibling::p[not(@style='TRH7')]`) which have the current
title as the most recent logical parent. Recall that `preceding-sibling` is a reverse axis so `p[…][1]` refers to the nearest sibling in reverse document order. Since `following-sibling::p[…]` selects all following non-title paras the second predicate `[generate-id(…)]` limits the selection to the logical children of the current title.

Comment: Thanks @urcodebetterznow its working can you please explain the second xsl transform in a clear manner.

Comment: @NaveenKumar: I updated my reply. Also see items 1 and 4 in the XSLT 1.0 FAQ page I linked to.

Comment: HI @urcodebetterznow how can we merge similar nodes which has no attributes into single node.

Comment: @NaveenKumar: To select all `p` elements that have no attributes you could say `<xsl:apply-templates select="//p[not(@*)]"/>`. If this isn't what you had in mind I suggest you ask a new question, including sample code.

Comment: Hi @urcodebetterznow can i get ur contact so that i can share the question and want to learn more about xslt like ur mail id ?